# Can't Clear/Format HDD or Partitions (Windows 10 Installation)

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-installation, io

So, here's what happened. I plugged in a bootable W10 installation thumbdrive. After deleting two preexisting partitions that I had made manually, the installer created a reserved system partition (partition 0), and a normal storage partition (partition 1). After this, it began installing Windows 10 on the HDD. However, it was stuck on 0% on "Preparing files for installation." Because of this, I exited setup, and tried the process again. After I selected the Custom installation, I see "Drive 0 Partition 1: System Reserved," and "Drive 0 Partition 2." I tried installing it on the second partition, but it brought up the error message, `Windows could not format a partition on disk 0. The error occurred while preparing the partition selected for installation. Error Code 0x80070057.`

After this, I tried restarting the installation, and format the partition with the UI format button. The following error message occurs: `We couldn't format the selected partition. [Error: 0x80070057]`.

After this, I tried to format both partitions with Diskpart. Both times, I was told that it couldn't be done because of an I/O error. When I tried to clear the disk and each of a partitions, it would happen again. Is there any way to fix these errors and install Windows?

Comment: Do you have UEFI bios? What's your HDD partition style, MBR or GPT?

Comment: I believe I use EUFI, but I'm not sure about MBR or GPT.

Answer (score 1):

Googling the error message turns up [this Microsoft page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2476568/error-0x80070057-when-you-format-a-hard-disk-drive-to-install-windows) that claims the error is caused by a bad pre-existing filesystem on the partition, and that the solution is to completely delete the partition and re-create it.

If you have problems even with that, I have two additional suggestions:

- **Use another OS** -- Whatever is giving Windows fits might not affect another OS. For instance, you could use an [Ubuntu Linux installation disk,](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) booted in its "try before installing" mode. You could use that to run GParted to re-partition the disk and prepare filesystems on it. Since the Linux tools don't share code with the Windows tools, they might not be affected by the Windows glitch.
- **Completely wipe the disk** -- You could completely zero out the disk. This will likely take several hours. See [this question and its answers](https://superuser.com/questions/1101006/how-to-completely-wipe-computer-including-os) for pointers to utilities that will do this. With nothing but "0" values on the disk, no utility should be confused when trying to partition and format the disk.

Comment: Hi, Rod. I appreciate the reply. The thing is, I only have one flash drive, and it was a miracle that my unreliable internet stayed up long enough to download windows 10 and write it to the flash drive (I used the media creation tool.) Is there any way I could wipe the disk with command prompt, or would I get a similar result?

Comment: See the 3rd link in his answer.

Comment: Alright, I've worked out, it's nothing to do with Windows. While trying to install Ubuntu, I was given a similar error message. While trying to use DBAN, it didn't recognize the HDD at all.

Comment: That sounds like a hardware failure, then. :(